# How to inspect XMLHttpRequest.ResponseText Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My **XMLHttpResponseText** object is coming as

```
<appto.models.Suggestion object at 0xc7aecd0>
```

How can I extract properties and valus associated in **Javascript**?

When I use `show(xmlHttpRequest.responseText)` in javascript, it errors out saying

```
Error show is not defined
```

I am using `firefox`

Thank you

Comment: Does `alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);` yield any results?

Comment: yes thats the same thing <appto.models.Suggestion object at 0xc7aecd0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 'show' must be a method defined somewhere in Eloquent Javascript, either add it to your script or, as already suggested use alert or consolsole.log.

For the actual response itself, 'appto.models.Suggestion object at 0x80b770' must be a problem with your server app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Net tab of Firebug to observe HTTP traffic, including XMLHttpRequest, or use `console.log` on the text from JavaScript to log to your browser's JavaScript console.  Where did you get `show` from?

Comment: The net tab is giving the same thing too <appto.models.Suggestion object at 0xc80b770>

Comment: Aha, gotcha. That <...> is what your Web framework is returning. This is a server side issue.

Comment: Okay, i'll try to see what I am doing wrong, thank you @Nicholas